# Android Studio won't open

Tags: java, android-studio

I downloaded android studio 4.2 for windows x64 and can't get it to open. I have been troubleshooting for hours but nothing I've been finding online has helped. I have JAVA_HOME set properly and I have java version 16.0.1. I have already tried a full uninstall/reinstall. Someone told me to run the studio.batch file and here is the result:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.<clinit>(IdeEventQueue.java:80)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.replaceSystemEventQueue(StartupUtil.java:750)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.patchSystem(StartupUtil.java:734)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:59)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$1$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:366)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at 
java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected java.lang.Runnable java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.runnable accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt.event" to unnamed module @197c8a05
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.findFieldInHierarchy(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.findAssignableField(ReflectionUtil.java:141)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil.findRunnableField(InvocationUtil.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil.<clinit>(InvocationUtil.java:24)
    ... 19 more
```

---

JRE 16.0.1+9-24 amd64 by Oracle Corporation
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1

New to all of this so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue right now. Trying to figure it out since last night. Help guys...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue for IDEA.

> IDEA uses reflection operations which can be forbidden in the future JDK releases.

[check issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210683)

[also check another issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266324)

Try switching to previous jdk versions